# Run launchd that runs a console app from Objective-C

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, objective-c++, launchd

I have an authentication app (authApp) that runs on Mac. AuthApp lets you log in to the Mac. It runs in place of the default login screen. I have added a new button in authApp and I want that button to launch another app (let's call it newApp) when clicked. AuthApp is written in Objective-C and newApp in Swift.

I am able to launch newApp from the login screen every time at logout with the help of launchd agents. But that is not what I want; I want it to open only when the button in AuthApp is clicked.

This is my launchd plist file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.example.apple-sample</string>
        <key>LimitLoadToSessionType</key>
        <string>LoginWindow</string>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
        <string>/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/newApp.app/Contents/MacOS/newApp</string>
        </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The file is saved in /Library/LaunchAgents. newApp is in /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools.

Is there a way to execute this launchd programmatically (Objective-C++/Swift) from the code so that newApp is launched? Please note this needs to be done before the user has logged in to the machine.

Comment: Is there a reason to use launchd for *newApp* itself? What about simply spawning *newApp* as a new subprocess of *authApp*? (e.g. `NSTask`, `posix_spawn()`, etc.) Another possibility would be Launch Services (e.g.  `LSOpenCFURLRef `, `NSWorkspace -launchApplicationAtURL:…`) but I'm not sure if they're available in the login window context.

Comment: Hi @pmdj I tried NSTask and NSWorkspace both are not able to launch before login.